# how can i copy one worksheet in one workbook into another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two separate workbooks one named ActiveWorkbook and one named Terminated Workbook. What I want to do is create a copy button on ActiveWorkbook--Templatesheet which will ask the user which sheet to copy and copy into TerminatedWokbook and named the same as the original one.

I have some code like this and since i am very new to excel macro, so of cause it does not work. Thanks

```
Sub CopytoTernimal()
Dim CopyName As String
CopyName = InputBox("Please enter the name of sheet which will copy to ternimal")

Sheets("CopyName").Copy
Before:=Workbooks("Terminated Employees").Sheets(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Since CopyName is a var, not a string, use `Sheets(CopyName)` with no quotes. And put that `Before` in the same line of the `Copy` command.

Comment: Thanks but i get the error "Subcript out of range" on the copy line

Comment: I believe that `before` is the problem. Be sure the CopyName exists and try without it.

Comment: I try copy with name and without it but get the same error message. sorry

Comment: Maybe bacause the name of the Worksheet should has.xml . I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's the complete code

```
Dim CopyName As String
CopyName = InputBox("Please enter the name of sheet which will copy to ternimal")

Dim thisSheet As Worksheet

'you must be sure CopyName is typed correctly, or it wont find the sheet
'also be sure the Activeworkbook name is correctly typed. 
Set thisSheet = Workbooks("ActiveWorkbook").Worksheets(CopyName) 

'copy this sheet
thisSheet.Rows.Copy

Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Set NewSheet = Workbooks("Terminated Employees").Worksheets.Add()
NewSheet.Name = thisSheet.Name
NewSheet.Paste
```

To make it a button, go to the main excel window, developer tab, and insert an `Active X Button`. (Use the Active workbook)
Then in `design mode`, double click that button. The `click event` will be automatically generated, so you put this code inside that sub. 
After that, disable the `design mode` (that's in the developer tab in main window as well).
When you click the button, code will be invoked.

Comment: Thanks but it do not like the line" NewSheet.Paste()"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still get the error on   Set thisSheet = Workbooks("VacSicLog.xlsm").Worksheets(CopyName).  Should i need give the full name of the worksheet incluing .xlsm and should both the workbook need be open. I am sorry. I every new to Excel

Comment: here is the whole code     Sub CopytoTernimal()
Dim CopyName As String
CopyName = InputBox("Please enter the name of sheet which will copy to ternimal")

Dim thisSheet As Worksheet


Set thisSheet = Workbooks("VacSicLog.xlsm").Worksheets(CopyName)

'copy this sheet
thisSheet.Rows.Copy

Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Set NewSheet = Workbooks("Terminated Employees.xlsm").Worksheets.Add()
NewSheet.Name = thisSheet.Name
NewSheet.Paste


End Sub
 and line "Set thisSheet = Workbooks("VacSicLog.xlsm").Worksheets(CopyName)" has error said "Run_time error'9', subscript out of range thank

Comment: The book needs to be open, yes. If it's not: `Workbooks.Open(fullpathofterminatedemployeesbook)`.
Then you can continue. When you use `Workbooks(name)`, the name is the title, not the full path.

Comment: Don't use the `xlsm` in the name, just in the full path to open.

Comment: Insterting, When i run the code in the MS vb module edit window it work great but when i try click the copy button it does not work.Where should i put the module? in the ternimatedworkbook or activeworkbook? does it need be public sub copytoternimal()

Comment: Button explanation inserted in answer.